# Why does my scanner repeat?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a GPA calculator but early on in the code I started having issues; here's the code segment:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
    int length = input.nextInt();

    String[] gradesArray = new String[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
        gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
```

it all goes well until the "Enter grade (include + or -) " part, it repeats twice, so when I compile and get to that part it says "Enter grade (include + or -) Enter grade (include + or -) " before I can type in anything. How can I fix this repeating issue? Because I think it also takes the spot of one grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding

```
input.nextLine();
```

after

```
int length = input.nextInt();
```

This will make sure that the end of the line that contained that integer is consumed before you try to read more input.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
int length = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

String[] gradesArray = new String[length];

for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
    gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

Further explanation:

Calling `input.nextInt()` attempts to read a single token from the standard input and convert it to an int. After you type that integer and hit enter, the input stream still contains the end of line character[s], which haven't been read by `input.nextInt()`. Therefore, the first time you call `input.nextLine()`, it reads those characters and then discards them (since `input.nextLine()` strips newline characters), and you end up getting an empty String. That empty String is assigned to  gradesArray[0], and the loop proceeds immediately to the next iteration. Adding an `input.nextLine()` before the loop solves the problem.

Comment: jesus christ, I love you right now. Would you mind explaining to me exactly why that works that way? :)